# How can I develope for Sharepoint 2010 on Vista 32-bit foundation using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have PC with Vista 32-bit. I must develope custom field for Sharepoint 2010 Foundation. When I try to create project for Sharepoint 2010, Visual Studio show message that I need to instal Sharepoint 2010. I have read that Sharepoint 2010 has 64-bit OS in system requirements.

Can I develope custom field using external Sharepoint 2010 server or can I instal Sharepoint 2010 Foundation on Windows Vista 32-bit?

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not be able to develop SharePoint components on a 32-bit machine.  You would need to use a 64-bit version of Windows and then either install SharePoint 2010 locally on the PC or use a virtual machine also running a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do it on Vista 64-bit but you can on Windows 7 64-bit though I don't necessarily recommend this. Your best bet would be on Windows Server 64-bit and I would recommend matching what ever your production environment is.

If this is not possible you may be out of luck with the SharePoint 2010 projects built into Visual Studio 2010 - though I'd be interested in being proven otherwise.

On the plus side you still should be able to use a third party Visual Studio extension called WSP Builder available on Codeplex (http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/30858 - make sure you get the 2010 Extensions beta version) and use the WSP Builder projects to develop for SharePoint. You will then be able to create WSPs for deploying to a test environment.

The only caveat to all of this is you will have to bring the necessary DLLs from a SharePoint server to your local PC so you may add them as references to your projects so that you may use the SharePoint API.

Overall I recommend getting a proper development environment for SharePoint because the Visual Studio 2010 projects are amazing compared to WSP Builder. It also makes for a much better development and testing experience.